# Scheduler not showing appointments

Tags: c#, devexpress, scheduler, appointment

My scheduler is not showing any appointments while in the debug the datasource is not empty:

[image]

The ID is the same as the resource ID.

My mappings are:

```
this.schedulerStorage1.Appointments.Mappings.Description = "Opmerking";
this.schedulerStorage1.Appointments.Mappings.End = "Eindtijd";
this.schedulerStorage1.Appointments.Mappings.ResourceId = "ID";
this.schedulerStorage1.Appointments.Mappings.Start = "Starttijd";
this.schedulerStorage1.Appointments.Mappings.Subject = "Handeling";
```

And the output image is:

[image]

Comment: Do you have selected the correct time period (year, month ...)?

Comment: Did you set the storage to the scheduler view?

Comment: The only thing I can think right now (sorry :)) is once again to check if it is properly bond Appointment to the Resource.

Comment: Yes Gusman, the storage is set. What do you mean Majkl?

Comment: Check if the Appointment is correctly bonded to Resources (If not than so you will not see it in the scheduler)

For example (do not use mapping, but directly connects)

`appoint.ResourceId = scKalendar.Storage.Resources.Items[i].Id;`

Comment: Did you check binding to resources?

Comment: It finally works after many tries. Don't know what actually the problem was.  Thanks for the help Majkl ;)